# Grails Spring LDAP Security multiple domain use case

Tags: spring, grails, plugins, groovy, ldap

I have several DC in my LDAP(like DC=Ny, DC=Oh) and would like to authenticate the user from LDAP through grails spring ldap plugin.

Initially I have used following parameters in the config.groovy file and was able to authenticate the users from newyork but now I have to authenticate the users from both newyork and Ohio.

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.test.SecUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.test.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.test.SecRole'

// LDAP config
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'CN=P8,OU=P8,OU=Weblogic,OU=PR,OU=Groups - Application,DC=NY,DC=GWL,DC=com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'test'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://NY.GWL.com:389/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true // typically needed for Active Directory
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'DC=NY,DC=GWL,DC=com' 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="sAMAccountName={0}" // for Active Directory you need this
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = ['mail', 'displayName'] // extra attributes you want returned; see below for custom classes that access this data
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider'] // specify this when you want to skip attempting to load from db and only use LDAP

What kind of changes needs to be done in groovy.config file or does I need to do any code changes.

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have a similar problem. Thanks.